# Incrementar variavel dentro de um foreach

Tags: php, array, loop, foreach

Como eu faço pra fazer uma variável incrementar dentro de um `foreach`?

```
foreach($adults as $adultos):
    $i = 1;
    echo "<strong>Quarto".$i++."</strong><br>";
    echo "Adultos:".$adultos."<br>";
endforeach;
```

Comment: Declare ela fora do loop.

Comment: Ela está incrementando normalmente na linha do 1º  `echo`. O problema real é que você reinicia ela a cada iteração.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, basta você deixar a definição da variável fora do laço:

```
$i = 1;

foreach($adults as $adultos):
    echo "<strong>Quarto".$i++."</strong><br>";
    echo "Adultos:".$adultos."<br>";
endforeach;
```

Caso contrário, a cada iteração do laço a variável é redefinida com o valor inicial 1.

Se seu *array* for sequencial, i.e. não associativo, você nem precisará da variável de controle `$i`, pois a própria chave acaba fazendo esse papel:

```
foreach($adults as $i => $adultos):
    echo "<strong>Quarto".($i+1)."</strong><br>";
    echo "Adultos:".$adultos."<br>";
endforeach;
```

Neste caso utilizei `$i+1` pois o índice do *array* se inicia em 0.

E a terceira opção é utilizando o laço `for`, como citado na [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238485/5878).

Comment: Muito Obrigado, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode só tirar a inicialização do laço:

```
$adultos = array( "a", "b", "c" );
$i = 1;
foreach ($adultos as $adulto):
    echo "<strong>Quarto " . $i++ . "</strong><br>";
    echo "Adultos: " . $adulto . "<br>";
endforeach;
```

Ou pode fazer o mais adequado neste caso que é usar o `for` normal:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($adultos); $i++) {
    echo "<strong>Quarto ". ($i + 1) ."</strong><br>";
    echo "Adultos: " . $adultos[$i] . "<br>";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qbBpFL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mlzaremi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/ForEachIncrement.php).